# Shiny modules namespace outside of UI for javascript links

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I am trying to use shiny modules to re-use the UI and server code to present off of three different data sets that share the same presentation.

Running into a bit of a challenge dealing with namespace when using javascript based modal popup link creation outside of the UI / server code.

Here is my non-working app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(id = c('a', 'b', 'c'), value = c(1, 2, 3))

on_click_js = "
Shiny.onInputChange('myLinkName', '%s');
$('#myModal').modal('show')
"

convert_to_link = function(x) {
  as.character(tags$a(href = "#", onclick = sprintf(on_click_js, x), x))
}
df$id_linked <- sapply(df$id, convert_to_link)
df <- df[, c('id_linked', 'value')]

mySampleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput(ns('myDT')),
      bsModal(id = 'myModal',
              title = 'My Modal Title',
              trigger = '',
              size = 'large',
              textOutput(ns('modalDescription'))
      ),
      width = 12
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(mySampleUI('myUI'))

myServerFunc <- function(input, output, session, df) {
  output$myDT <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(df, escape = FALSE, selection='none')
  })
  output$modalDescription <- renderText({
    sprintf('My beautiful %s', input$myLinkName)
  })
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(myServerFunc, 'myUI', df)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

A working version would successfully display `myLinkName` in the description portion of the modal pop up. The reason this code does not work is because the UI component ID value is created outside of the UI code without the namespace containment. I get that. But, I am not able to figure out how to re-work it so that the name space matches.

Any ideas / options?

Answer (score 6):

I've created a sample app that would add a button to each row of the datatable and if the button is pressed it will create a plot based on that row. Note that the clicked row is also recorded for later use and saved in a variable called `SelectedRow()`. Let me know if you need more clarification

```
rm(list = ls())
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

# This function will create the buttons for the datatable, they will be unique
shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {inputs <- character(len)
                                           for (i in seq_len(len)) {
                                             inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))}
                                           inputs
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Menu Item 1", tabName = "one", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "one",h2("Datatable Modal Popup"),
              DT::dataTableOutput('my_table'),uiOutput("popup")
              )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactive({
    testdata <- mtcars
    as.data.frame(cbind(View = shinyInput(actionButton, nrow(testdata),'button_', label = "View", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),testdata))
  })  
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable(my_data(),selection = 'single',options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10),server = FALSE, escape = FALSE,rownames= FALSE)

  # Here I created a reactive to save which row was clicked which can be stored for further analysis
  SelectedRow <- eventReactive(input$select_button,{
    as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
  })

  # This is needed so that the button is clicked once for modal to show, a bug reported here
  # https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/issues/57
  observeEvent(input$select_button, {
    toggleModal(session, "modalExample", "open")
  })

  output$popup <- renderUI({
    print(input$select_button)
    bsModal("modalExample", "Sample Plot", "", size = "large",
            column(12,renderPlot(plot(rnorm(1:10),type="l",col="red",main = paste0("You selected Row Number: ",SelectedRow())))
                   )
            )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Step 1: Generate the Table with buttons**

As you can see there is a button called `View` for each row

[image]

**Step 2: Once the button is clicked the plot will be produced**

Note that the title of the plot changing based on the clicked row

[image]

Comment: While this is very good effort, I don't want to do it that way. Anyways, I figured out that by creating the Shiny `namespace` in the global environment, and using `paste` to string together the javascript link is the way to go. Not happy with the hacky code, but seems to do the trick. `ns <- NS('myUI')`;  Then, `on_click_js = paste("Shiny.onInputChange('", ns('myLinkName'), "', '%s'); $('#myModal').modal('show')", sep = "")`

Comment: Very useful for me. But it doesn't work if you click the same button twice. Because the value is not updated there is nothing that triggers the modal to show.

Comment: @Gopala, can you explain the role of '%s'. My modules without JS works when `output$plot<-renderUI({})` and `plotOutput(ns(plot))`. However, when I call a have JS to read a value from JS into R module using `Shiny.onInputChange`.... this does not render as expected. Because, now the plotOutput is `someID-plot`. How did you address this ? Can you update your answer on this thankyou